# Why do we have a namespace for Android?

Tags: android, namespaces

I just don't get it.

When we write a XML based layout in Android we use the string `"xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".`

Ok, and now someone is going to say "to prevent collisions" and "if I make a different namespace *then what, huh?*". But nobody really writes a competing schema and then tries to run their Android app with it.

Put another way, if I leave the default as empty, nothing works. But why did Google make the choice that nothing would work if this was the case? It shouldn't be that hard to read the XML and work out the elements, so why was that particular design decision made?

Comment: Why does XML have namespaces? Why do we have standards and tools to test XML documents? Why would anyone care if their document is valid?

Comment: @tadman well, given the purpose of this xml - to be used by a software system to create code - one has to wonder why there is a need to confirm the uniqueness of the created xml. It's not like this is a system processing multiple different formats, and it needs to know which is what - so you might, I suppose if you were curious - wonder why the design choice was made.

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not suitable for Stack Overflow. Usually, the only party that can answer definitively is Developer X, and they are unlikely to see the question, let alone answer it. Everyone else can only offer opinions. Also, please bear in mind that the decision was made 10-12 years ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare rats, i was hoping someone here might know, and given it's a very popular framework thought it might be answerable, and also provide a valuable design explanation.

Comment: Well, XML namespaces are generally a good idea (if you're designing multi-party XML). After all, we use a few in Android XML files (`android`, `app`, and `tools`, to name three). In some of the XML files, though, element names map to Java class names (e.g., layouts), and I assume that drove the decision to not apply namespaces for element names. As to why they didn't just use the default namespace, I have wondered that for a decade. But, at this point, it's entirely possible that the people who made that decision aren't even on the Android project anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment by CommonWare (apologies, I'm unsure if this question might get closed, so i'm putting this up while i can!)

"
*Well, XML namespaces are generally a good idea (if you're designing multi-party XML). After all, we use a few in Android XML files (android, app, and tools, to name three).*

*In some of the XML files, though, element names map to Java class names (e.g., layouts), and I assume that drove the decision to not apply namespaces for element names.*

*As to why they didn't just use the default namespace, I have wondered that for a decade. But, at this point, it's entirely possible that the people who made that decision aren't even on the Android project anymore.*
"

So the default namespace is used so that we can have different namespaces in the general AndroidManifest.xml file - like `app` and `tools`, as well as `android`.

In other files, as element names map to fully qualified java package names, there is no reason to have a namespace, as all element names are thus guaranteed to be unique.

The original design decisions are not recorded anywhere readily accessible, but if you do know please share!